# Overriding istream get(char)

Tags: c++, iostream

I'm implementing a few very specific I/O streams, one of them, an input stream that has data available only sometimes (think about some kind of socket that you poll for data while it is open). My streams are based on a class that inherits from basic_iostream and internally use a buffer that inherits from basic_filebuf. So my filebuf has a special way of signalling that there's no data available when underflow is called. I thought it's a good idea, because technically it's not EOF, unless the channel really gets closed. This status basically says - "there's no data now, but the channel is open, so you can keep asking, it might arrive eventually".

The problem is `traits_type::eof()` is checked inside `get(char)` function which does not exactly look like it was supposed to be overriden (maybe I'm wrong).

But anyway - what would be the best way of signalling such state? If such state occurs, I would know about it in my buffer's underflow method...

Comment: There is no "try again later" state for the iostreams, instead they usually block wating for more input. Compare to the normal `cin` using a keyboard - `get`waits for the next keypress, it has no "not right now" signal.

Comment: Exactly, that's what I'm fixing here.

Answer (score 1):

For this propose you can use [a user defined char_traits](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/char_traits), and put it as the template parameter to your `basic_filebuf` i.e. something like:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <limits>

struct my_char_traits : public std::char_traits<char> 
{
  typedef std::char_traits<char>::int_type int_type;
  static constexpr int_type eof() noexcept 
  {
    return std::numeric_limits<int_type>::min();
  }
};

class my_buff: std::basic_filebuf<char, my_char_traits>
{
};
```

Comment: OK, sounds promising. I used my_char_traits as template argument for my buffer class, adding a nda (no data available) fn that just returns a magic int. So what exactly will happen std::istream::get when underflow returns this magic value returned by nda()?

Comment: Read the following manual https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/get `Return value
1) the extracted character or Traits::eof()
2-6) *this`

Comment: In any case, if you are looking into asynchronous API i.e. would like to read when data became available you'd better forget about stream API at all. I.e this can be only a shim from asynchronous API to synchronous, so that end of the istream not actually freeing your socket or pipe, steam API is strict synchronous. Otherwise you'd better use  Asio or invent some continuation wheal like https://github.com/incoder1/IO/blob/refactor/examples/asynch_network_client/main.cpp